# Can a tar.gz file contain malicious code? Is a Mac vulnerable to such a tar.gz?

Tags: macos, tar, gzip

Can a `tar.gz` file contain malicious code that is similar to ZIP file? On a Mac particularly?

Edit:

Oops, I meant to ask the process of opening/untar a tar file on the Mac.  Not the contents of the result.

Comment: Any file can contain malicious code.

Comment: Any archive format allows storage of executables - all precautions apply, in the very same manner as to removable drives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

#### What is a Tar?

A [Tape ARchive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) is a file format to store multiple files within a single container, in order to *archive* them easily assuming that they will not be modified.

Gz means that it is compressed using gzip algorithm.

For the transitive property, since a tar file contains other files of any format, and since an executable file may contain malicious code, then a tar can contain malicious code.

Opening a tar itself to inspect is generally safe, however computer security practices still require to avoid opening files from untrusted sources and perform an antivirus scan.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, any archive can (potentially) contain malicious code.

To build off of what 'usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ' said, not only can a malicious executable lurk inside of the archive, but the archive structure can be set up such that the archive *is* the virus (sort-of).

When the archive contains a malicious executable, one usually has to enable the executable bit on most Linux and UNIX systems since it'll be automatically turned off by the program 'umask' (at least on Linux, not sure about MAC or UNIces).

As for the archive being a virus, it's something called a zip bomb.  It's an old technique used to cause a buffer overflow on the antivirus, primarily on windoze, since it used to be that the antivirus would un-archive everything in the downloaded package in order to parse for viruses.  These days, the antivirus just says 'screw it' if the zip bomb has a great enough recursion depth.

Google 'zip bomb' or '42.zip' for more.

Comment: Looks like we all have been downvoted, wow!

Comment: Probably since the question wasn't detailed/showed little research.  Our answers are still great though!